# Summing in VBA with a variable column and range

Tags: vba

I know this question gets asked a lot but I haven't been able to find the answer I'm looking for.  I'm trying to write a code that will be able to find a key term and then sum that column for a certain amount of rows.

I've tried simply replacing "G" in this code with my variable for the correct column (col) and I've made sure that my column variable is matching to the correct column.

```
Cells(subRow, col).Formula = "=SUM(G" & row & ":G" & subRow & ")"
```

The above, for example, works; but I would like it to look like this:

```
Cells(subRow, col).Formula = "=SUM(col" & row & ":col" & subRow & ")"
```

I've tried moving the col variable around in and outside of the quotes, and I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `col` is a variable so you add it to the string like you did `row`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the case you have described, you would have to use R1C1 Reference Style:

```
Cells(subRow, col).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=SUM(R" & row & "C" & col & ":R" & subRow & "C" & col")"
```

Comment: This compiles but it isn't giving me my desired result, as I debug it I find the right column that I want to sum and it correctly finds the rows that I want summed, and then in that line of code it moves to an entirely different column and row.  Any ideas why?

Comment: str = "column I want summed"
col = FindColumn(str, numCol)

Comment: FindColumn just finds the column number that contains the string

Comment: OK you have to use R1C1, and I have edited the answer as such.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a `Cells(row, column).Resize(number of rows, number of columns)` option :

```
Cells(subRow, col).Formula = "=SUM(" & Cells(row, col).Resize(subRow - row, 1).Address(0, 0) & ")"
```